# The operation has timed out on uploading document and updating metadata in sharepoint library using clientcontext.executequery()

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I wrote a program using CSOM to upload documents to SharePoint and insert metadata to the properties. once a while(like every 3 months) the SharePoint server gets busy or we reset IIS or any other communication problem that it may have, we get "The operation has timed out" error on clientContext.ExecuteQuery(). To resolve the issue I wrote an extension method for ExecuteQuery to try every 10 seconds for 5 times to connect to the server and execute the query. My code works in the Dev and QA environment without any problem but in Prod, when it fails the first time with timeout error, in the second attempt, it only uploads the document but it doesn't update the properties and all the properties are empty in the library. It doesn't return any error as result of ExecteQuery() but It seems from the two requests in the batch witch are uploading the file and updating the properties, it just does uploading and I don't know what happens to the properties. It kinda removes that from the batch in the second attempt!

I used both upload methods docs.RootFolder.Files.Add and File.SaveBinaryDirect in different parts of my code but I copy just one of them here so you can see what I have in my code.
I appreciate your help.

```
 public static void ExecuteSharePointQuery(ClientContext context)
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        bool isExecute = false;

        while (cnt < 5)
        {
            try
            {                    
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                isExecute = true;
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cnt++;
                Logger.Error(string.Format("Communication attempt with SharePoint failed. Attempt {0}", cnt));
                Logger.Error(ex.Message);
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                if (cnt == 5 && isExecute == false)
                {
                    Logger.Error(string.Format("Couldn't execute the query in SharePoint."));
                    Logger.Error(ex.Message);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
 public static void UploadSPFileWithProperties(string siteURL, string listTitle, FieldMapper item)
   {
       Logger.Info(string.Format("Uploading to SharePoint: {0}", item.pdfPath));

       using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL))
       {
           using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(item.pdfPath, FileMode.Open))
           {
               try
               {
                   FileCreationInformation fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation();
                   fileCreationInformation.ContentStream = fs;
                   fileCreationInformation.Url = Path.GetFileName(item.pdfPath);
                   fileCreationInformation.Overwrite = true;

                   List docs = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);

                   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);
                   uploadFile.CheckOut();

                   //Update the metadata
                   ListItem listItem = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields;

                   //Set field values on item
                   foreach (List<string> list in item.fieldMappings)
                   {
                       if (list[FieldMapper.SP_VALUE_INDEX] != null)
                       {
                           TrySet(ref listItem, list[FieldMapper.SP_FIELD_NAME_INDEX], (FieldType)Enum.Parse(typeof(FieldType), list[FieldMapper.SP_TYPE_INDEX]), list[FieldMapper.SP_VALUE_INDEX]);
                       }
                   }
                   listItem.Update();                       
                   uploadFile.CheckIn(string.Empty, CheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn);

                   SharePointUtilities.ExecuteSharePointQuery(clientContext);                      

               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {

               }
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Maybe in addition to retrying, you could explicitly set the clientcontext’s timeout value to something longer

Comment: I changed it in IIS and config file before that seems didn't work. I added to the code this time to see if it helps at all but I should wait for the next time that problem happens in the server but I was looking to see if there is any other solutions

Answer (score 0):

There's too many possible reasons for me to really comment on a solution, especially considering it's only on the prod environment.

What I can say is that it's probably easiest to keep a reference to the last uploaded file. If your code fails then check if the last file has been uploaded correctly.

Side note: I'm not sure if this is relevant but if it's a large file you want to upload it in slices.

Comment: I have a log file to keep track of everything. There is nothing wrong with the last file and sometimes the file size is only 10k but it still fails